# Equivalent of "this" keyword in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

Can you tell me please how to write the next code in vb.net?

```
public static bool IsYear(this string data)
    {
        return data.Length == 4 && Regex.IsMatch(data, @"[12]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]");
    }
```

Comment: You mean extension methods. This has nothing to do with what `this` _usually_ does in C#. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Comment: yes it was in a static class with extension methods

Comment: Tag your question with relevant tags, like [tag:VB.NET] and [tag:extension-methods]

Comment: There is no problem! I'm new here and a beginner, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: @Benjamin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186622/close-link-does-nothing-on-mobile-site-ios-android

Comment: @Flo Right, now you might want to add some content to the question. Explain the behavior you'd like (of extension methods), show your efforts (what didn't you understand from the mdsn page) and tell us what part of the syntax you're stuck on :) Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: OP: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175705/what-should-be-the-close-reason-for-convert-translate-my-code-questions

Comment: What a horrible name for such a function! There is no way to understand what it does without seeing the implementation.

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you. Now, that I read the MSDN references everything is clear. The problem was about "this" keyword for which I didn't find a correspondent. I needed to check if in a string array I have a single year or an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN article on VB extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).  Applying it will lead to something like this.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myString As String
        myString = "1955"
        Console.WriteLine(myString & " is Year =" & myString.IsYear)
        myString = "3955"
        Console.WriteLine(myString & " is Year =" & myString.IsYear)
        myString = "19555"
        Console.WriteLine(myString & " is Year =" & myString.IsYear)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
Module Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsYear(ByVal data As String) As Boolean
        Return data.Length = 4 And Regex.IsMatch(data, "[12]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]")
    End Function
End Module
```